# ADF Copy Data FIRE_TRIGGERS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

i read that the ADF Copy Data uses bulk insert but its not calling SQL Triggers.
In a sql query bulk statement i can activate 'FIRE_TRIGGERS' to solve this problem, is there a possibility to use the ADF Copy Data with SQL Triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bulk insert with SQL triggers using FIRE_TRIGGERS.

First, make sure you have right permissions to use BULK commands. Grant bulk operations permissions to user accessing from ADF in SQL database.

```
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO [user];
```

**ADF pipeline:**

1. In the `copy data` activity, connect the source to source DB and select the ‘Query’ option under the Use query property.
2. In Query, write the bulk insert script with FIRE_TRIGGERS.
3. In Sink, connect the sink database to copy data from the source.

**Source:**

**Query-**

```
BULK INSERT Sales
FROM 'Sales.csv'
WITH (
 DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
 FIRSTROW = 2, 
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
 ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
 FIRE_TRIGGERS);

select * from SalesLog
```

[image]

**Sink:**

[image]